# How to delete an instance from a python class

Tags: python, class

I have asked this question previously but was advised that I included too much unnecessary code so I am going to ask with less code now and hopefully what I include is more on track.

I am trying to allow a member to leave the Team if they so wish. By doing this, the system will delete all their details from the system. I am receiving an error with my code. Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong and how this can be achieved?

I would like my add members and remove members to update all the time, based on user input and the needs of the members. I hope this makes sense!

Below is my code:

```
all_users = []

class Team(object):
    members = []  # create an empty list to store data
    user_id = 1

    def __init__(self, first, last, address):
        self.user_id = User.user_id
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.address = address
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@python.com'
        Team.user_id += 1

    @staticmethod
    def remove_member():
        print()
        print("We're sorry to see you go , please fill out the following information to continue")
        print()
        first_name = input("What's your first name?\n")
        second_name = input("What's your surname?\n")
        address = input("Where do you live?\n")
        unique_id = input("Finally, what is your User ID?\n")
        unique_id = int(unique_id)
        for i in enumerate(all_users):
            if Team.user_id == unique_id:
                all_users.remove[i]

def main():
    user_1 = Team('chris', 'eel', 'london')
    user_2 = Team('carl', 'jack', 'chelsea')

    continue_program = True
    while continue_program:
        print("1. View all members")
        print("2. Want to join the team?")
        print("3. Need to leave the team?")
        print("4. Quit")
        try:
            choice = int(input("Please pick one of the above options "))

            if choice == 1:
                Team.all_members()
            elif choice == 2:
                Team.add_member()
            elif choice == 3:
                Team.remove_member()
            elif choice == 4:
                continue_program = False
                print()
                print("Come back soon! ")
                print()
            else:
                print("Invalid choice, please enter a number between 1-3")
                main()
        except ValueError:
           print()
           print("Please try again, enter a number between 1 - 3")
           print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: This is unfortunately still too much code. Try to remove any unnecessary code until you only have the code that causes the error left.

Comment: The python stack trace shows the exact line with the problem. Even if the example is kinda big, it lets us find the bad line and look nearby for the problem. So post the full error!

Comment: Aside from the error, I'd say the general design of your program -- combining Team and Users into a single class, storing the program state on the class, having the class modify global variables -- are all bad design decisions and will likely lead to other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Lets focus on the removal code:

```
for i in enumerate(all_users):
    if Team.user_id == unique_id:
        all_users.remove[i]
```

`enumerate` returns two values: the index and the object at the index. In your case, `i` is a `tuple` of those two values. `.remove` is a function, not a collection so `.remove[i]` will fail. Even then, its the wrong tool for the job: it scans the list for `i` and removes it. You just want to delete. Finally, once you've changed the list, you need to stop the enumeration.

So, to clean this up:

```
for i, user in enumerate(all_users):
    if user.user_id == unique_id:
        del all_users[i]
        break
```